# Is there any way that I can get latitude and longitude for multiple addresses a one time?

Tags: google-maps

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=address&output=csv

Like in this way, I put something to replace the address above, I would get the latitude and longitude in a CSV format

Can I get latitude and longitude for multiple addresses at a time?

Because I need about 300 locations, and sending the request too fast cause Google to think I'm flooding and ignore my later requests

Any help or suggestion is helpful

:P

Eric